# trying to make "inplace" work in my extension for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, oop

I wrote the following class to remove trend from my pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("detrend")
class detrend:
   def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
       self._obj = pandas_obj
   def percent(self, inplace=False):

       change_m = self._obj.copy()
       for name in change_m.columns:
           col = self._obj[name]
           change = (col[col.first_valid_index()] /
                     col[col.last_valid_index()])**(1 / (col.count() - 1))
           change_m[name] = change
           change_m[name] = change_m[name].cumprod()
       result = change_m * self._obj
       if (inplace == True):
           self._obj = result
       return(result)
```

the method works fine and returns the correct dataframe. 
the only part that is confusing me is the following:

```
       if (inplace == True):
          self._obj = result
```

When I pass inplace=True, the changes are not saved into the original dataframe.
what am I doing wrong? how should I make inplace work in my method?

Comment: First, check if your logic is ok and add a `print(':+)')` inside your `if (inplace == True):`. Suggestion: Use just `if inplace:` instead.

Comment: Did you find the problem? I almost had the same question as you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63184757/best-way-to-write-an-inplace-option-in-a-python-method

Someone told me the whole method won't change df inplace if you noninplace changed df even once in the method. But he doesn't tell me why and how to modify

My method also can't change df inplace