# Best way to write an inplace option in a python method

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm writing a extension for sklearn preprocessing. I have problem to write a 'inplace' version of the method you would typically see in many pandas methods. So my methods can either return a new df or change the input df directly.

```
class OneHotEncoder(preprocessing.OneHotEncoder):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    categories : 'auto' or a list of array-like, default='auto'
        Categories (unique values) per feature:
        - 'auto' : Determine categories automatically from the training data.
        - list : ``categories[i]`` holds the categories expected in the ith
    
    I'm saving a lot of description here
    """
    # @_deprecate_positional_args
    def __init__(self, n_values=None, categorical_features=None,
                 categories=None, drop=None, sparse=True, dtype=np.float64,
                 handle_unknown='error'):
        super().__init__(n_values, categorical_features, categories, drop, sparse, dtype, handle_unknown)

    def encode(self, X, columns, inplace: bool = False):
        """Encode categorical features as a pandas dataframe.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : pandas dataframe.
        columns : a list of str.
            Indicate which columns you wish to encode.
        inplace : bool, default False
            If True, do operation inplace and return None.

        Return
        ----------
        encoded_X : One-hot encoded dataframe if inplace=False
        """
        new_data = X.copy()
        if not isinstance(columns, collections.Sequence):
            raise TypeError("Input must be a sequence-like parameter 'columns'")
        if len(columns) == 0:
            raise ValueError("Input must not be empty parameter 'columns'")
        if isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            encoded_n_array = super().fit_transform(new_data.loc[:, columns]).astype(self.dtype).toarray()
            # categories_dict = dict(zip(columns, self.categories_))
            col_names = []
            for i, column in enumerate(columns):
                num_categories = len(self.categories_[i])
                if self.drop == 'first':
                    # If only one category is present, the feature will be dropped entirely.
                    if num_categories != 1:
                        num_categories = len(self.categories_[i]) - 1
                        col_names.append(np.char.add(np.repeat(column + '_', num_categories), self.categories_[i][1:]))
                    else:
                        continue
                elif self.drop == 'if_binary' and num_categories == 2:
                    col_names.append(np.array([column + '' + self.categories_[0][1]]))
                else:
                    col_names.append(np.char.add(np.repeat(column + '_', num_categories), self.categories_[i]))
            col_names = np.concatenate(col_names, axis=0)
            encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(encoded_n_array, columns=col_names)
            new_data = pd.concat([new_data, encoded_df], axis=1)
            new_data = new_data.drop(columns=columns)
            if inplace:
                X = new_data         ################ here the inplace does change anything. 
            else:
                return new_data
        else:
            raise TypeError("Input must be a DataFrame parameter 'X'")
```

Basically I'm inputting a X to the encode method. I want to be able to change input X inplace or just return a new copy. I changed X copy `new_data` for many times. But unable to change X inplace. I know my way is wrong. But how to change it? Thank you.

Comment: If you apply at least one operation on a dataframe that can't be done inplace (like "pd.concat") you can't apply the whole function inplace on that dataframe.

Comment: @MichaelButscher why is that? Could you please provide a reference to this issue? So i can learn a little. Also if this is the case how can I make the change? Thank you

Comment: It is just logical. To make a function work inplace on an object (dataframe here), every operation in the function applied to the object must be inplace. If one is not this creates a new object and the caller of the function must finally work with this (or another) new object which means it isn't inplace. Particular reason here is that rows can't be appended to or removed from dataframes inplace.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Ok i got it. So I won't make this method inplace. Thank you